# Why is it dataframe.head() in python and head(dataframe) in R? Why is python like this in general?

Tags: python

Beginner here. Shouldnt the required variables be passed as arguments to the function. Why is it variable.function() in python?

Comment: Python is object-oriented. The data frame is an object, and you can call an object's method (a function). `head()` in Python is a method of the `pandas.DataFrame` object. Take a look at the pandas source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

`foo.bar()` does the same thing as `foo.__class__.bar(foo)`

so it *is* a function, and the argument *is* passed to it, but the function is stored attached to the object via its class (type), so to say. The `foo.bar()` notation is just shorthand for the above.

The advantage is that different functions of the sams name can be attached to many objects, depending object type. So the caller of `foo.bar()` is calling whatever function is attached to the object by the name "bar".  This is called polymorphism and can be used for all sorts of things, such as generic programming. Such functions are called methods.

The style is called object orientation, albeit object orientation as well as generic programming can also be achieved using more familiar looking function (method) call notation (e.g. multimethods in Common Lisp and Julia, or classes in Haskell).